# How to make a union of two tables in sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two simple table is `sqlite3` and I am trying to write a simple query using the `UNION` operator that returns the table that consists of all tuples that are in either of the relations.

I am writing:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test UNION test2
```

Unfortunately, though it's returning:

```
Error: near "test2": syntax error
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Everything seems like it should work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the syntax should be:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM test 
UNION 
SELECT col1, col2 FROM test2
```

Also, make sure you are selecting the same number of columns from both tables, and that the columns are made up of the same data types.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't appear to be a valid place for a `UNION`. According to [this schema](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html), you would have to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test
UNION
SELECT * FROM test2
```

As grantmc points out, the columns have to be union-compatible as well. I'm not sure if `SELECT *` is even valid in a union, but I wouldn't recommend it if it was anyway.